# Angular-ui modal - pass data into modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, jquery-isotope

I am trying to pass some model data into a modal window when it is opened. When the user clicks on an element I want to have the modal window open and display more detailed information relating to what was clicked on.

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSYG9OkrgPRG5D0YVKmk?p=preview) that works how I want it to except for passing the data into the modal window.

I am trying to pass the data in using ng-click:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.picture}}" width="100" ng-click="open(item)"/>
```

Can anyone help me with this? or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/tO6HPlYoYcRRj6wNpdPd?p=preview)?

I added the item to the resolve

```
resolve: {
    items: function () {
        return $scope.items;
    },
    item: function(){
        return size;
    }
}
```

And in the `controller` I am doing: `$scope.item = item;` after injecting the `item`

Answer (score 16):

I've made a plunker for you at http://plnkr.co/FzU5SOv3pdZmAPAIOzdo.

You want to resolve your data much like you do items currently.

```
$scope.open = function (size) {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    },
    size: function() {
      console.log('size: ', size);
      return size;
    }
  }
});
```

and in your modal controller make sure to include the now resolved size object as follows:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items, size) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };
  $scope.size = size;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to create an object within `resolve` that returns an object that holds the variables that I wanted to share.

```
resolve: {
  shared: function(){
    return {
      name: 'Spencer',
      numbers: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }
}
```

To access the `shared` object, include it when defining your modal instance controller.

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceController', function($scope, shared, $uibModalInstance,
```