# Why is this parameter for modal is always undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass values to a modal over parameters. For some reason this parameter is always `undefined` when I try to access it in my controller. The second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747154/angular-ui-modal-pass-data-into-modal) is what I am building upon.

Here is my setup for the modal. Please note that `$scope.evaluationResult` is defined and has valid content.

```
$scope.showEvaluationResult = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'evaluation-result/evaluation-result-dlg.html',
        controller: 'EvaluationResultDialogCtrl',
        windowClass: 'evaluation-result-dlg',
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            evaluationResult: function() {      
                return $scope.evaluationResult;
            }
        }
    });
    setupKeyHandling(modalInstance);
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
/**
 * The controller for displaying evaluation results.
 */
annotatorApp.controller('EvaluationResultDialogCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$modalInstance', '$http',
    function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, $http, evaluationResult) {
        $scope.trainingLog = {
            text: ''
        };

        $scope.close = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.evaluationResult = evaluationResult; // Always undefined

    }]);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: I not see `'evaluationResult'` inside your inject array - `['$scope', '$modal', '$modalInstance', '$http',`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Yeah, that was it.. I am new to AngularJS .. actually I just have to overtake a project from another colleague. ^^ Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put it in injection array, should be:

`annotatorApp.controller('EvaluationResultDialogCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', '$modalInstance', '$http', 'evaluationResult',
    function ($scope, $modal, $modalInstance, $http, evaluationResult) {`

Comment: It should be in single quotes in the injection array, though: `'evaluationResult'`.